# how to prove this epsilon-delta property for continuous functional calculus with normal elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $ A$ be a C* algebra, $f\in C([-1,1])$. Prove that for every $\epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0,$ s.t. for $\forall x \in A, x=x^*, \| x \| \leq 1$ and $\forall y \in A, \|y\| \leq 1$, we have $\|xy-yx\| \leq \delta \implies \|f(x)y-yf(x)\| \leq \epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

We will need to assume that $A$ is unital first, but by a unitization argument you can get the general case. (As long as the claim itself is modified to state that $f(0)=0$.)

First let $f(t)=t^k$ for $k\ge0$.  In order to see it in this case, observe the following string of estimates holds:

$||x^ky-yx^k||=||\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(x^{k-j}yx^j-x^{k-j-1}yx^{j+1})||\le\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}||x^{k-j}yx^j-x^{k-j-1}yx^{j+1}||\le \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}||x^{k-j-1}(xy-yx)x^j||\le \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} ||xy-yx||=k||xy-yx||$

where here we have used that $||x||\le 1$, and $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra.

Now, consider the case where $f$ is a polynomial.  We get that by the triangle inequality.

The case where $f$ is merely continuous follows by density, thanks to the fact that $y$ is in the unit ball.  The last remaining hypothesis not explicitly used so far is $x$ being self-adjoint, which could just as well be replaced by normality.  It is used to ensure the functional calculus is even defined to begin with.